# .htaccess sub domain as file parameter with all the variables

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to make this url redirect using .htaccess (linux/apache) ..

I want to keep "as is" all calls for www sub domain like this

```
www.example.com/index.php
www.example.com/test.php?id=1&name=a
www.example.com/whatever.php?whateverurl=xxxx
```

but I want to redirect all wild card urls like this with the sub domain as extra variable to current unlimited-whatever url variables

for example

```
xxx.example.com -> example.com/?subdomain=xxx
yyy.example.com/index.php -> example.com/index.php?subdomain=yyy
whatever.example.com/test.php?var=1 -> example.com/test.php?subdomain=whatever&var=1
whatever.example.com/whatever.php?var1=1&var2=2 -> example.com/whatever.php?subdomain=whatever&var1=1&var2=2
```

is this possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you set up your [Wildcard DNS Record](http://ma.tt/2003/10/wildcard-dns-and-sub-domains/) you should make your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\??(.*)?$ $1?host=%{HTTP_HOST}&%{QUERY_STRING} [L] [L]
```

This rule works, although it will provide you the whole host, rather than just the subdomain, which you'll have to parse in your PHP.

Comment: Glad to help, sorry it wasn't perfect. However, I did realize the `RewriteCond` line should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example\.com$`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer

this rule seems to works

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ $1?subdomain=%1 [QSA,L,NE]
```

for the time without problems ...

thanks again for your answer

Best regards

Vangelis